# Using @covers for a class

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am using php for testing my code. Here is an example:

```
/**
 * @covers Calculator::
 */
class CalculatorTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    protected function setUp() { /* ... */ }
    /**
     * @covers Calculator::add
     */
    public function testAddTwoIntegers() { /* ... */ }
    /**
     * @covers Calculator::multiply
     */
    public function testMultiplyTwoIntegers() { /* ... */ }
}
```

However, my code is complicated and I want to get rid of @covers over individual test methods. How does php treat the following class when generating coverage reports:

```
/**
 * @covers Calculator
 */
class CalculatorTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    protected function setUp() { /* ... */ }

    public function testAddTwoIntegers() { /* ... */ }

    public function testMultiplyTwoIntegers() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Notice that the @covers annotation over a class is still there but I have removed it from every method.

I am able to get coverage reports using this approach too but I have not seen an example of it anywhere, so I want to know if this is not a correct use.

```
Code Coverage Report:
  2016-01-18 08:57:50

 Summary:
  Classes: 17.67% (56/317)
  Methods:  0.33% (5/1520)
  Lines:    0.60% (109/18094)

Class1:
  Methods:  66.67% ( 2/ 3)   Lines:  95.45% ( 21/ 22)
Class2:
  Methods:  50.00% ( 3/ 6)   Lines:  96.70% ( 88/ 91)
```

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, setting the classname without the method name is the recommended `@covers` syntax.

Documentation here:

https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.5/annotations.html#covers

```
Annotation
@covers ClassName::methodName (not recommended)
@covers ClassName (recommended)
@covers ClassName<extended> (not recommended)
@covers ClassName::<public> (not recommended)
@covers ClassName::<protected> (not recommended)
@covers ClassName::<private> (not recommended)
@covers ClassName::<!public> (not recommended)
@covers ClassName::<!protected> (not recommended)
@covers ClassName::<!private> (not recommended)
@covers ::functionName (recommended)
```

When you ask:

> How does php treat the following class when generating coverage reports

The answer is: Every line of the class mentioned in `@covers` executed during "any" of the tests in that TestCase will compute a +1 in the execution.

If you do real TDD and start **first** by writing the test, **then** writing the class, this is a perfect approach. Some of your lines in your public methods with branches will count 2 or more executions, and probably the lines inside each of the branches will count 1 execution.

Private methods will also count +n executions, while you won't write named tests for those methods, they will be called as a result of being helpers to the public methods.

When you say:

> but I have not seen an example of it anywhere

I can tell that 90% of our tests use a `@covers MyNiceClass` annotation without specifying any method.

If you start by the test first, you normally won't mess up things. If you "need" that "MyNiceClass" is able to get something, you start by doing `testGetSomething()` in the test and set a basic expectation, then you write the `public function getSomething()` in the class and you end up having a one-to-one test for each method in 80% of the cases. The rest of the cases normally are multiple tests for the same method like for example `testGetSomething()` (happy path) and `testGetSomethingThrowsExceptionWithInvalidParameter()` (sad path).

### In short

Yes, what you propose is correct, normal, usual and it is the recommended way to go according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason (which was the reason in my case) is not using the complete class-name including the namespace.

```
// Should be like
@covers \App\Module\MyClass::doSomething
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply run the test case and see the coverage with your changes?

From the [PHPUnit manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html):

```
The @covers annotation (see Table B.1) can be used in the test code to specify
which method(s) a test method wants to test. If provided, only the code 
coverage information for the specified method(s) will be considered. Example 
11.2 shows an example.
```

[Table B1 Referenced above](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.covers.tables.annotations)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had generated reports and tinkered around a bit too like deleting a few test methods and then regenerating reports and the coverage reduced. So, now I am wondering if I am using it correctly.

Comment: While I have not used this directly, the @covers does not appear to truly affect your results for coverage metrics, but is more an indicator of what is being tested.  The resulting tests and coverage are then used for that block, as I read the manual.